# Klein's curve (algebraic geometry)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I can't find any information about the canonical ring of Klein's quartic curve (the one with 168 automorphisms). I would imagine there is a lot known about the structure of this ring. Can anybody help me please? Thank you!

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? The syzygies in the minimal free resolution of the canonical ring, a la Green's conjecture?

Comment: I added the AG tag. I hope that's OK.

Comment: your question is **tautological**

Comment: YES!  thank you folks (really lots of interesting info), what I meant if "a la Green's conjecture" (I had notes 100 years ago but I can't find them; however, not about this specific curve; I vaguely recall there were remarks about a rank-2 bundle over the curve, must have been an extension of K_X). I wanted to know this ring as precisely as possible, to construct explicit bases of H^0(nK_X) (yep, I should have used additive notation to go with the word "divisor"); a related issue are of course higher Weierstrass points.

Comment: GOT IT!  It's in David Eisenbud's Green's Conjecture: An Orientation (1991). The structure of the canonical ring of curves is known for genus less that or equal to 8 (at that time...) and also for smooth plane curves of any genus, so... it's overkill! John Mangual: You may be happy to see the abstract "tries to explain the attractiveness of canonical rings"... but the article is a little technical. Listen everybody, I had such a great experience here, it was my first time daring to post on MO and I enjoyed hearing back and learning the things that you found beautiful, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

Klein quartic, $X$, is a smooth degree $4$ plane curve, given by the equation $F(x,y,z) = x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x = 0$. Doesn't this mean that the canonical ring is $k[x,y,z]/(x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x)$?

Details: This embedding is the canonical embedding, since we compute by adjunction that $\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the canonical bundle. Thus, we have an injection $k[x,y,z]/F \hookrightarrow \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} H^0(X, K^{\otimes n})$. The Hilbert series of the left hand side is $(1-t^4)/(1-t)^3 = 1+3t + \sum_{n \geq 2} (4n-2) t^n$. The Hilbert series of the canonical ring is $1+gt + \sum_{n \geq 2} ((2g-2)n-(g-1)) t^n$. These match, so the map is an isomorphism. (Actually, I think I recall that the canonical ring of a nonhyperelliptic curve is always generated in degree $1$, but it seemed easier to check the Hilbert series in this case.)

Comment: You recall correctly that the canonical ring of a nonhyperelliptic curve is always generated in degree 1. That's a theorem of Max Noether.

Answer (score 2):

There are many resources for this, one of easy treatments can be found in

https://www.math.hmc.edu/~ursula/teaching/math189/finalpapers/julia.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen this gorgeous reference; but, my question was about the ring structure of \oplus H^0(X,K^n), where X is the curve and K the canonical bundle

Answer (score -6):

Not sure what "canonical" means in this context.  Half of algebraic geometry is called "canonical ring" or "fundamental class" or some other vacuous term.

---

Please consider Elkies [The Klein Quartic in Number Theory](http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/elkies.pdf) and in general the book **The Eightfold Way** is online.  In the translation of [Klein](http://library.msri.org/books/Book35/files/klein.pdf)'s original work we find this futuristic image:

[image]

Also in [German](https://eudml.org/journal/10142).  The translated version has improved images

---

I have no idea what the above really means, but it sounds like we get really lucky.  These results are due to Riemann -- long before Serre, Grothendieck, Hartshorne or Shafarevich.  How could he have anything more complex in mind?

The only ring mention in Klein's paper is $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3y + y^3z+z^3x)$ -- the one David Speyer wrote -- as well as $SL(2, \mathbb{F}_7)$ and $\mathbb{Z}(\frac{1 + \sqrt{-7}}{2})$.  Which one is the canonical ring?

Since $x, y, z$ are the coordinates of an  equation $x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x = 0$, then $x, y, z$ can be thought of as parameterizing solutions to the set $$\{x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x = 0\}$$

So the coordinate ring might be the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^N$ mod a single relation:
$$ \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x ) $$
In fact, $x, y, z$ are **sections** of the line bundle $\mathcal{O}_X$ and if $i+j+k = n$ then maybe we can multiply them to get sections of the other sheafs:
$$ x^i y^j z^k \in H^0(X, n \mathcal{O}_C)$$
Looks like the coordinate ring is the direct sum of all of these possibilities excepting for the possibility that $x^3 y + y^3z + z^3 x = 0$.

---

If we then re-read Klein, there is even more to say:

\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \sum_{\beta \equiv 1 \mod \sqrt{-7}} \mathrm{Re}(\beta) \, q^{\beta \overline{\beta}/7}  \\
y &=& \sum_{\beta \equiv 2 \mod \sqrt{-7}} \mathrm{Re}(\beta) \, q^{\beta \overline{\beta}/7}  \\
z &=& \sum_{\beta \equiv 4 \mod \sqrt{-7}} \mathrm{Re}(\beta) \, q^{\beta \overline{\beta}/7}  
\end{eqnarray}

and these theta functions explicitly solve the equation $x^3 y + y^3 z + z^3 x = 0$ in terms of modular functions over $\mathbb{H}/SL(2, \mathbb{F}_7)= \langle z \mapsto z + 7, z \mapsto - \frac{1}{z} \rangle $.  These sections $x,y,z \in \mathbb{H}$ are **modular cusp forms of weight 2** over $X(7)$ -- one must verify that $x, y, z, \neq 0$ exceept at the "cusps".

The fact that these theta functions parameterize a curve both on $\mathbb{H}$ and in projective space $\mathbb{P}^3$ does not seem trivial at all.  A lot of effort may go into showing the rather strange-looking coordinates we chose do not have exceptional behavior.

And these are generators of your canonical ring!

---

[Birational Geometry Old and New](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-01/S0273-0979-08-01233-0/home.html) (Antonella Grassi) has this much to say:

> **Example-Theorem 29**: If $C$ is a curve of genus $g \geq 2$ the divisor $3 K_C$ is *very ample*.  There is an embedding $\phi: C \to \mathbb{P}^N$ such that if $H$ is a hyperplane $H \cdot C = 3K_C$.  Then the canonical ring $R(C, K_C)$ can be reconstructed from the coordinate ring of $\mathbb{P}^N$.  In particular, $R$ is finitely generated.  In fact $3K_C$ determines a *pluricanonical embedding*.

Antonella Grassi explain that nothing too exceptional occurs, so that for example $K_C = \mathcal{O}(-1)$, and the coordinates $x,y,z$ can be identified with hyperplanes $\{ x=0\}, \{ y = 0\}, \{z=0\}$ and then $[x],[y],[z]$ are **hyperplane divisors** and $H\cdot C$ is just setting $x$, $y$, or $z = 0$.

For much more please turn to the standard texts:

- Hartshorne **Algebraic Geometry**
- Shafarevich **Basic Algebraic Geometry**

Comment: John: I have been called many names in my (long) life, but this is the first time I'm being called "vacuous": that is BRILLIANT!  that's exactly what I am. Thank you, I had read the book but many readers will benefit from your reference! My answer to your puzzlement (in the slight chance you care to know) is in the comment to Amdeberhan, but my vacuousness (now that I know) is eternal! :-)

Comment: How can you say that the canonical ring $$R(X, \, K_X) = \bigoplus _{n \in \mathbb{N}} H^0(X, \, nK_X)$$ is a *vacuous term*?

Comment: If you're not sure what "canonical ring" means in this context, maybe this is not a question for you to answer? Any algebraic geometer can understand the question perfectly well.

Comment: I occasionally turn to MO in the mornings as a respite from reading the news. I thought that at least here we would all understand what words actually mean.

Comment: I think, Emma, that the noun from "vacuous" is not "vacuousness", but "vacuity".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Algebraic geometry has the "fundamental class", the "canonical ring", the "tautological bundle".  They are called these named for a reason.  There's no need to take it personally -- these terms are vacuous.

Comment: I beg your pardon, john – did I appear to be taking something personally?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Not at all!  All I am saying is that **algebraic geometry** itself can be difficult to learn, due to it's ambiguous jargon.

Comment: OK, but what does that have to do with addressing a comment to me in which you write "There's no need to take it personally" – what were you referring to?

Comment: @GerryMyerson this discussion is vacuous - and possibly my answer - I have moved on to the next question

Comment: Gerry: Special thanks!  (I love words), I too thought the noun was "vacuity" but it sounded a tad weird, so I googled... and to me, google rules! (vacuousness was the first to come up, plus it's on freedictionary, and as we mathematicians--but, do I qualify?--all know, the best things in life are free)

Comment: @EmmaPreviato you are certainly not vacuous, these algebraic geometry terms are